# phpMyAdmin no me deja entrar

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin

Me meti a phpMyAdmin y me puse a ver las bases, toque MySQL y modifique algo (jeje por andar de tenton) y ya no me deja entrar Me pone "El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso" y abajo dice que esta bloqueado dice "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/3118): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Account is locked." que puedo hacer?? ya instale nuevas versiones de MYSQL y phpMyAdmin y sigue el error!! Todo esto es en laragon, ayuda por favor!

Comment: Linux o Windows?

Comment: ¿Qué modificaste?

Comment: Era Windows y ni idea que modifique!! pero gracias!! termine haciendo lo que mucho!! desinstale todo desde laragon y volvi a empezar de cero!! prometo no andar tocando si no se para que es!! Saludos a ambos y feliz 2024!!